# Transpose results of several SUM queries. Is this possible?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

I built a report based off a query that summed multiple values from a single table. It's essentially a Year To Date report, in this case, Pesticides received year to date. While the report works as a quick reference check, these totals need to be plugged (copy/pasted) into a master excel sheet that keeps a running "available balance" inventory. When I export the totals to an excel from the report, the data is not in the format it needs to be.  It's horizontal instead of vertical. I can copy the data, paste it to Excel, transpose it and then copy/paste the data to where it belongs,but was wondering if it could be transposed when the query outputs the totals.

I tried the crosstab method but that appears to apply to a single table, and this query displays the sums of the columns.  Perhaps I did it wrong using the crosstab method, but I tried many different ways and did not get the desired result.

Here's is the SUM query

```
SELECT 
     Agnique_MMF_Recieved.[SumOfAgnique MMF],
     Altosid_30_Day_Recieved.[SumOfAltosid 30 Day],
     Altosid_SR-20_Recieved.[SumOfAltosid Liquid SR-20],
     Altosid_Pellets_Recieved.[SumOfAltosid Pellets],           
     Altosid_WSP_Recieved.[SumOfAltosid WSP],
     Altosid_XR_Recieved.[SumOfAltosid XR],
     Altosid_XRG_Recieved.[SumOfAltosid XRG],
     Aquabac_200G_Recieved.[SumOfAquabac 200G],
     BVA_2_Recieved.[SumOfBVA 2 Oil],
     Four_Star_BTI_Received.[SumOfFourStar BTI],
     Golden_Bear_Recieved.[SumOfGolden Bear],
     Metalarv_S-9_Recieved.[SumOfMetalarv S-9],
     Sustain_MGB_Recieved.[SumOfSustain MGB],
     Vectobac_GS_Received.[SumOfVectobac - GS],
     Vectobac_12AS_Recieved.[SumOfVectobac 12AS]
FROM 
     Agnique_MMF_Recieved,
     Altosid_30_Day_Recieved,
     Altosid_Pellets_Recieved,
     Altosid_SR-20_Recieved,
     Altosid_WSP_Recieved,
     Altosid_XR_Recieved,
     Altosid_XRG_Recieved,
     Aquabac_200G_Recieved,
     BVA_2_Recieved,
     Four_Star_BTI_Received,
     Golden_Bear_Recieved,
     Metalarv_S-9_Recieved,
     Sustain_MGB_Recieved,
     Vectobac_12AS_Recieved,
     Vectobac_GS_Received;
```

I would like the data to end up looking like

SumofAgniqueMMF as the row header and next to it a totals column with the value from the sum.

Anyway, is this possible?    Thanks!

Comment: You should use an explicit cross join instead of the long outdated comma separated list of table names.

Answer (score 0):

Can I assume that each of those tables in your `FROM` clause are single-record tables/views with just a single SUM in them?

if so:

```
SELECT 'SumOfAgnique MMF' AS [Description],
    Agnique_MMF_Recieved.[SumOfAgnique MMF] AS [Sum] 
    FROM [Agnique_MMF_Recieved]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SumOfAltosid 30 Day' AS [Description], 
    Altosid_30_Day_Recieved.[SumOfAltosid 30 Day] AS [SUM] 
    FROM [Altosid_30_Day_Recieved]
...etc
```

Comment: Damn you guys are good!  That worked, @Tim. My Facilities Manager & Director will be very happy you exist!  Have a great weekend and thanks again!

Comment: The original statement worked, but when I try and add more to it I keep on getting a "Syntax Error from FROM clause".  I even copied your data twice and still got the error.  Any ideas?

Comment: `UNION ALL` goes between each `SELECT` statement, did you miss that maybe?

Comment: That was it!!  Thanks again, Tim

Answer (score 0):

Consider: t==> a table, f ==> a field, r ==> a result set.

`select r1.s1, r2.s2 ... rn.sn 
from
(
    (select sum(f1) as s1 from t1) r1,

    (select sum(f2) as s2 from t2) r2,

    ...
    ...
    (select sum(fn) as sn from tn) rn

)`